# How to pass a generic type into a new generic object?

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

I have two classes, Character and Npc which both inherit from a base class called 'Actor'. Consider the following two methods which are basically almost identical:

```
public static Dictionary<uint, Npc> drawnNpcs = new Dictionary<uint, Npc>();
public static Dictionary<uint, Character> drawnCharacters = new Dictionary<uint, Character>();
```

---

```
private GameObject DrawCharacter(ActorWrapper actorToDraw)
{
    GameObject obj;
    if (Data.drawnCharacters.ContainsKey(actorToDraw.Id))
    {
        Character character;
        Data.drawnCharacters.TryGetValue(actorToDraw.Id, out character);
        obj = character.gameObject;
        obj.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        obj = new GameObject("Actor");
        Character character = obj.AddComponent<Character>();
        character.Id = actorToDraw.Id;
        Data.drawnCharacters.Add(character.Id, character);
    }
    return obj;
}

private GameObject DrawNpc(ActorWrapper actorToDraw)
{
    GameObject obj;
    if (Data.drawnNpcs.ContainsKey(actorToDraw.Id))
    {
        Npc npc;
        Data.drawnNpcs.TryGetValue(actorToDraw.Id, out npc);
        obj = npc.gameObject;
        obj.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        obj = new GameObject("Actor");
        Npc npc = obj.AddComponent<Npc>();
        npc.Id = actorToDraw.Id;
        Data.drawnNpcs.Add(npc.Id, npc);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I've tried to implement a generic method which takes in a generic Dictionary to try and merge these two methods together. (I'm not even really sure if this will work at all, it was just a naive first attempt)

```
private GameObject GetDrawnActor<T>(Dictionary<uint, T> drawnActors, ActorWrapper actorToDraw) where T : Actor
{
    if (drawnActors.ContainsKey(actorToDraw.Id))
    {
        T actor;
        drawnActors.TryGetValue(actorToDraw.Id, out actor);
        GameObject obj = actor.gameObject;
        obj.SetActive(true);
        return obj;
    }
    else
    {
        GameObject obj = new GameObject("Actor");
        var actor = obj.AddComponent<typeof(T)>(); //how do i do this??
        actor.Id = actorToDraw.Id;
        drawnActors.Add(actor.Id, actor);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

The commented line is where it fails.

Edit: Really dumb solution to this! I modified the code to be all correct except for the offending line given by the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the only thing you have to do is to replace this:

```
Character character = obj.AddComponent<typeof(T)>();
```

with this:

```
Character character = obj.AddComponent<T>();
```

Comment: Well. I feel stupid. I got passed that line, thanks :)

Comment: @Toofy you shouldn't...I am glad that I helped :) You are welcome !